How to Measure the Impact of Adding a Translation Layer to Large Language Models?
I'm currently exploring the integration of a translation layer into Large Language Models (LLMs) to preprocess all inputs into a uniform language (English) before processing by the model. The idea is to potentially reduce the complexity and size of the dictionary needed by LLMs, which often exceeds 100,000 tokens due to the diversity of languages and encodings they must handle.
I'm seeking insights on methodologies or metrics that can be used to quantify the impact of such a translation layer on various aspects of LLM performance, including:

Efficiency Improvement: How can we measure the change in processing speed or computational resource usage before and after integrating the translation layer?
Accuracy and Integrity: What metrics or tests can be applied to ensure that the translation layer does not compromise the quality or integrity of the data being processed?
Security Enhancement: Are there specific benchmarks or tests to evaluate the improvement in security, especially concerning vulnerabilities linked to processing non-standard language inputs?
Scalability Impact: How might the addition of a translation layer affect the model's scalability, particularly in handling large volumes of diverse data?

I'm particularly interested in practical approaches or case studies that have tackled similar challenges in LLMs or related AI fields. Any advice, references, or tools that could guide the implementation and evaluation of this translation layer would be greatly appreciated.
